# How to find where nil value is being unwrapped in project in xcode with Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, null

I got a very common error, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". This happens when I press a button that is supposed to segue to another view controller, not when I run the app. I know what this error means, but the probelm is I do not know where it is, it doesnt tell me in the debugger area. When I press the button it takes me to the this page where there is a breakpoint at a line that displays...

```
Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
```

0x41d094 <+72>:  trap

How do I find where a nil value is being unwrapped?

Also this happens when I click a button, therefore I thought it must be in the action method for that button (buttons im my case since I have one action method for 5 buttons). Here is the code for that method. It is not neccesary that a nil value is being unwrapped in this method, but if you find something please help me out.

```
    @IBAction func btnGridSensorClick ( sender: UIButton) {  

        var aStrQuery: String = ""  

        if sender.tag == 1021  
        {  
            //Temperature  
            aStrQuery = "Select * from SensorDetail where SensorType = 'Temperature' order by sensorDate DESC limit 1"  
            print("Temperature button clicked")  
        }  
        else if sender.tag == 1022  
        {  
            //Humidity  
            aStrQuery = "Select * from SensorDetail where SenorType= 'Humidity' order by sensorDate DESC limit 1"  
            print("Humidity button clicked")  
        }  
        else if sender.tag == 1023  
        {  
            //Gas  
            aStrQuery = "Select * from SensorDetail where SensorType = 'Gas' order by sensorDate DESC limit 1"  
            print("Gas button clicked")  
        }  
        else if sender.tag == 1024  
        {  
            //Flame  
            aStrQuery = "Select * from SensorDetail where SensorType = 'Flame' order by sensorDate DESC limit 1"  
            print("Flame button clicked")  
        }  
        else if sender.tag == 1025  
        {  
            //Motion  
            aStrQuery = "Select * from SensorDetail where SensorType = 'Motion' order by sensorDate DESC limit 1"  
            print("Motion button clicked")  
        }  

        mutArrAlertList = Database.shareDatabase().SelectAllFromTable(aStrQuery)  

        if mutArrAlertList.count > 0  
        {  
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailVC", sender: self.mutArrAlertList.objectAtIndex(0))  

        }  

        else  
        {  
            tblListView.hidden = true  
            lblNoData.hidden = false  
        }  
    }
```

If the nil value is not in the above method, then how can I find where the nil value is being unwrapped in the project?

Comment: You can set a breakpoint at the start of your method and then go line by line. When it crashes you know where you are and what causes the crash.

Comment: Ok sanjana I will do this

Comment: Thank you Jonas, I will use your method.

Comment: I printed it and I get this the following in the below comment.

Comment: {
    AdditionalInfo = "Optional(<null>)";
    SensorType = Temperature;
    alert = "Optional(Temperature reached to 37.3.Board: raspberrypi.Time: 2016-02-09T15:38:02.0000000)";
    id = 1;
    isChecked = NO;
    sensorDate = "2016-02-09 15:38:02 +0000";
}